# Replace non UTF-8 from String

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a table that has strings with non UTF-8 characters, like `�`. I need to change them in order they have back all accents, and other latin characters, like: `cap� to capó`. The field is a VARCHAR.

So far, I have tried:`SELECT "Column Name", regexp_replace("Column Name", '[^\w]+','') FROM table`

And:
`CONVERT("Column Name", 'UTF8', 'LATIN1')` but don't work at all.

For instance, the error I get is: "Regexp encountered an invalid UTF-8 character (...)"

I have seen other solutions, but I can't go on them because I cannot change the table because I am not administrator.

Is there any whay to achieve this?

Comment: � is a marker to your users to tell them that programmers mishandled their text and lost some of it (except in cases where � is under discussion, like this web page). Try to find out if the database actually contains � (if so, the text is lost), or if the problem in is in your retrieval and display. What is the collation of the column? Please [edit] to show your code and tag with your programming language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the database encoding is UTF8, then *all* your strings will contain *only* UTF8 characters. They just happen to be different characters than you want.

First, you have to find out what characters are in the strings. In the case you show, � is Unicode codepoint FFFD (in hexadecimal).

So you could use the `replace` function in PostgreSQL to replace it with ó (Unicode code point F3) like this:

```
SELECT replace(mycol, E'\uFFFD', E'\u00f3') FROM mytab;
```

This uses the Unicode character literal syntax of PostgreSQL; don't forget to prefix all strings with escapes in them with `E` for extended string literal syntax.

There are odds that the character is not really �, because that is the “REPLACEMENT CHARACTER” often used to represent characters that are not representable.

In that case, use `psql` and run a query like this to display the hexadecimal UTF-8 contents of your fields:

```
SELECT mycol::bytea FROM mytab WHERE id = 12345;
```

From the UTF-8 encoding of the character you can deduce what character it really is and use that in your call to `replace`.

If you have several characters, you will need several calls to `replace` to translate them all.

Comment: Hello Laurenz, thank you for your reply. This is not working, it returns the same, including the �. And I want to replace all Uni Code characters, not only this one. Is there any way to do this? I am really stuck here.

Comment: Then your character is not really �. Odds are that you have a font that cannot display the real character and uses the replacement character instead. I'll add something to the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right Laurenz. I tried this: `select CAST ('�' AS BYTEA)`, but for every  � returns ÀÂ, even if is not the same. For example, it should be cap� = capó or as� = así

Comment: You have to run the query in `psql` which will show hex output (unless you are using an ancient version of PostgreSQL), not pgAdmin or some other GUI. Moreover, you should not copy and paste the character, but query it directly from the table like in the example in my answer.