# Replace Unicode Character “�” (U+FFFD) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I replace the Unicode character "unknown" [character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FFFD) in SQL Server?

I would like to mimic [this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298796/replace-non-utf-8-from-string) from postgres, for SQL Server.  How can I achieve this?

```sql
SELECT REPLACE('asdf�', E'\uFFFD', E'');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a specific Unicode Character in MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197784/replacing-a-specific-unicode-character-in-ms-sql-server)

Comment: hey @GSerg, i saw that answer, but it doesn't seem to work in my case `SELECT REPLACE (N'asdf�' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'ˌ', '')`

Comment: Because you want to replace `�`, not `ˌ`? So for you it would be `select replace(N'asdf�' collate Latin1_General_BIN, N'�', N'')`?

Comment: @GSerg yikes.... thanks

Comment: Warning: this specific "replacement character" can be *shown* when the actual character value is invalid as Unicode codepoint. So it may not be really cp 65533 - which will mean that the replace will fail.

Answer (score -1):

I often use the below query to identify the ASCII character code

```
SET TEXTSIZE 0;  
-- Create variables for the character string and for the current   
-- position in the string.  

DECLARE @position    INT,
        @string      NVARCHAR(50);  
-- Initialize the current position and the string variables.  

SET @position = 1;
SET @string = 'asdf�'

select @string
WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@string)
    BEGIN
        SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)),
               CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)));
        SET @position = @position + 1;
    END;  
GO
```

This returns the ASCII character code that can be built into a replace:

```
REPLACE('asdf�',CHAR(63),'')
```

To add to Hans Kesting's response above, this would also help identify the actual character  thats causing the issue.